# Using NuGet Package Manager Console to install EMGU OpenCV for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv

I've installed the EMGU OpenCV library for C#. But when I try to use it, I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Emgu.CV, Version = 2.4.2.1777, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = `7281126722ab4438`' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Clearly the package installed successfully because if I try to reinstall the package using the NuGet package manager console it says

```
PM> Install-Package VVVV.EmguCV
'VVVV.EmguCV 2.4.2.1' already installed.
CAIT already has a reference to 'VVVV.EmguCV 2.4.2.1'.
```

I don't see the problem here...

EDIT: Oh before you ask, the dll files are in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Download And Installation

I don't know about the NuGet package (didn't try that), but you might want to look at an article on the Emgu wiki which describes download and installation of Emgu http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation

### Creating Your First EMGU Image Processing Project

> A complete guide to show new comers to EMGUcv on how to set up their project step by step.

You might also want to checkout this article on Codeproject for creating your first Emgu project
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257502/Creating-Your-First-EMGU-Image-Processing-Project

Comment: However the link provided for Download And Installation, is showing using the NuGet to install the package.